# Script to Delete Tables With A Prefix

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am running SQL Serve 2008 and we have a few test tables that were obviously used for testing.  The prefix of the tables are Test_, my question is, will this script delete all tables with the prefix of Test_ on the database I execute it on?

```
declare @cmd varchar(4000)
declare cmds cursor for 
select 'drop table [' + Table_Name + ']'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where Table_Name like 'Test%'

open cmds
while 1=1
begin
  fetch cmds into @cmd
  if @@fetch_status != 0 break
  exec(@cmd)
end
close cmds;
deallocate cmds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will this script delete all tables with the prefix of Test_ on the database I execute it on?

Yes, it will `DROP` tables. DELETE is normally used with deletion of data. Your script will physically drop the tables.

Also, please [dont use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) and there is no need for a cursor. Your script can easily be written using dynamic sql.

---

**EDIT :** In comments, [@MartinSmith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith) pointed to one of his [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/1387418) - that I was not aware ... but is an eye opener when concatenating. (To be honest, I have never faced, but now will be aware of the gotcha ! Thanks again Martin !)

> The ONLY guaranteed mechanism are the following:
>
> - Use cursor to loop through the rows in specific order and concatenate the values
> - **Use for xml query with ORDER BY to generate the concatenated values**
> - Use CLR aggregate (this will not work with ORDER BY clause)

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql = (select N'drop table ' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N';'
FROM sys.tables AS t
WHERE t.name LIKE N'Test_%'
order by object_id 
 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.','nvarchar(max)')

print @sql ;
-- caution below will ACTUALLY drop the tables.
-- review the output and then uncomment below line
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: sorry for my inaccurate SQL terminology.  DROP is what I was after.  If not to use Information_Schema how should it be coded?

Comment: @BobJonesGodfreyLovesToEatSush please see my update. Also, be careful, when you have tables with `Test_` vs `Test`. You can accidentally drop TestPROD table :-)

Comment: This is not a guaranteed approach to string concatenation https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/606786/concatenation-into-a-scalar-variable-using-linked-server-in-from-clause-fails-when-casting-or-converting-data

Comment: @MartinSmith isn't that true only for linked server ?

Comment: No it is never guaranteed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank you .. Learned something new today ! I have updated my answer.